# R random forest using cforest, how to plot tree

Tags: r, random-forest

I have created random forest model using `cforest`

```
library("party")    
crs$rf <- cforest(as.factor(Censor) ~ .,
  data=crs$dataset[crs$sample,c(crs$input, crs$target)],
  controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=500, mtry=4))
cf <- crs$rf 
tr <- party:::prettytree(cf@ensemble[[1]], names(cf@data@get("input")))  
#tr

plot(new("BinaryTree", tree=tr, data=cf@data, responses=cf@responses))
```

I get error when plotting tree

> Error: no string supplied for 'strwidth/height' unit

Any help how to overcome this error?

Comment: please post a reproducible example so we can see what you're trying to do (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: One hack given in the last answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924402/cforest-prints-empty-tree

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I assume that crs is referring to a data frame. The dollar sign may be a problem (specifically crs$rf). If crs is indeed a data frame, then the $ would tell R to extract items from inside the dataframe by using the usual list indexing device. This may be conflicting with the call to generate the random forest, and be causing the error. You could fix this by starting with:

```
crs_rf <- cforest(as.factor(Censor) ~ ., .....
```

Which would create the random forest object. This would replace:

```
crs$rf <- cforest(as.factor(Censor) ~ ., ......
```

As a reference, in case this doesn't fix it, I wanted to refer you to a great guide from Stanford [that covers random forests](http://www.stanford.edu/~stephsus/R-randomforest-guide.pdf). They do have examples showing how the party package is used. In order to make trouble shooting easier, I might recommend pulling apart the call like they do in the guide. For example (taking from the guide that is provided), first, set the controls:

```
data.controls <- cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000, mtry=3)
```

Then make the call:

```
data.cforest <- cforest(Resp ~ x + y + z…, data = mydata, controls=data.controls)
```

Then generate the plot once the call works. If you need help plotting trees using cforest(), you might think about looking at this excellent resource (as I believe the root of the problem is with your plotting function call): http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-tour-of-the-trees-and-forests/

Comment: I tried both suggested solutions but still have same error, here is new code                 data.controls <- cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000, mtry=3) 
crs_rf <- cforest(as.factor(Censor) ~ .,
      data=crs$dataset[crs$sample,c(crs$input, crs$target)], controls=data.controls)
cf <- crs_rf
tr <- party:::prettytree(cf@ensemble[[1]], names(cf@data@get("input"))) 
#pt


plot(new("BinaryTree", tree=tr, data=cf@data, responses=cf@responses))

Comment: Let's forget about the plotting for a moment. Can you put in the calls 1 at a time into R, run them, and show the output in your message. Also, what about changing as.factor(Censor) to as.factor(crs_rf$Censor)

Comment: Show the output of this call first: data.controls <- cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000, mtry=3)

Comment: Then, show the output of this call after: crs_rf <- cforest(as.factor(Censor) ~ ., 
                  data=crs$dataset[crs$sample,c(crs$input, crs$target)], controls=data.controls)

Comment: Also, if you type crs, what is the output? I am concerned about this line: data=crs$dataset[crs$sample,c(crs$input, crs$target)]. Check if you get an error when you run this.

Comment: partial output of data.controls    ## An object of class "ForestControl"
## Slot "ntree":
## [1] 1000
## 
## Slot "replace":
## [1] FALSE
## 
## Slot "fraction":
## [1] 0.632
## 
## Slot "trace":
## [1] FALSE
##

Comment: and output of cforest i.e.crs_rf ## 
##   Random Forest using Conditional Inference Trees
## 
## Number of trees:  500 
## 
## Response:  as.factor(Censor) 
## Inputs:  ip1,ip2  
## Number of observations:  2431

Comment: also when i print "tr" it shows the tree in text format

Comment: So, I am confused on the error then. You have a tree that has been generated, which means all the original calls are correct. The problem then is the plot part of the last function (if I understand, to generate the tree). Do you get the error when you type this command: plot(new("BinaryTree", tree=tr, data=cf@data, responses=cf@responses))

Comment: So, at least the suggestion of breaking the call out, which was made above, helped :-) Can you take out the new() wrapper

Comment: I think the plot call format is off. I am looking here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf

Comment: what if you just do plot(crs_rf) or plot(tr)

Comment: plot(crs_rf) gives error Error: cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'. plot(tr) gives error ## Error: 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Comment: i am using cforest not party package,

Comment: I see. But this call in your code is calling the party package: tr <- party:::prettytree(cf@ensemble[[1]], names(cf@data@get("input"))).

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the introduction to the party package: "
Based on conditional inference trees, cforest() provides an
implementation of Breiman's random forests. The function mob()
implements an algorithm for recursive partitioning based on
parametric models (e.g. linear models, GLMs or survival
regression) employing parameter instability tests for split
selection. Extensible functionality for visualizing tree-structured regression models is available"