# Weights in cforest 'tree' add up to more than sample size

Tags: r, random-forest, party

This is my first time asking a question here so please be kind... and I apologise if this isn't the correct place to ask this question (the line between programming in R and a stats question can be a bit blurred to me) - if so I will happily try stackexchange.

I am running cforest in R (party package) to predict a numerical response variable, and using the excellent 'get_cTree' workaround suggested by @Marco Sandri here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534978/9989544
to generate a tree to try to understand the rules it's using to split (that's of interest to me even though my main focus is variable importance).

I was expecting the weights, across all of the nodes, to sum to my total sample size, which is what happens if I run a single 'ctree'.

However, what is actually happening, when using Marco Sandri's get_cTree code is that multiple pairs of nodes weights sum to my sample size, and the remaining weights do not sum to my sample size at all. The overall total of weights is more than my total sample size.

Is this a natural consequence of trying to get a tree out of a conditional forest - i.e. it isn't truly partioning the data into individual nodes? - or is this something that could be resolved with programming?

Here is an example (get_cTree code from Marco Sandri). For the iris dataset, n=150. The sum of the weights for the nodes that I get for the cforest is 566, and it's 150 using ctree (party package).

```
library(party)

update_tree <- function(x, dt) {
  x <- update_weights(x, dt)
  if(!x$terminal) {
    x$left <- update_tree(x$left, dt)
    x$right <- update_tree(x$right, dt)   
  } 
  x
}

update_weights <- function(x, dt) {
  splt <- x$psplit
  spltClass <- attr(splt,"class")
  spltVarName <- splt$variableName
  spltVar <- dt[,spltVarName]
  spltVarLev <- levels(spltVar)
  if (!is.null(spltClass)) {
    if (spltClass=="nominalSplit") {
      attr(x$psplit$splitpoint,"levels") <- spltVarLev   
      filt <- spltVar %in% spltVarLev[as.logical(x$psplit$splitpoint)] 
    } else {
      filt <- (spltVar <= splt$splitpoint)
    }
    x$left$weights <- as.numeric(filt)
    x$right$weights <- as.numeric(!filt)
  }
  x
}

get_cTree <- function(cf, k=1) {
  dt <- cf@data@get("input")
  tr <- party:::prettytree(cf@ensemble[[k]], names(dt))
  tr_updated <- update_tree(tr, dt)
  new("BinaryTree", tree=tr_updated, data=cf@data, responses=cf@responses, 
      cond_distr_response=cf@cond_distr_response, predict_response=cf@predict_response)
}

attach(iris)

SepalLength <- as.numeric(iris$Sepal.Length)

SepalWidth <- as.numeric(iris$Sepal.Width)

PetalLength <- as.numeric(iris$Petal.Length)

PetalWidth <- as.numeric(iris$Petal.Width)

Species <- as.factor(iris$Species)

mtry=ceiling(sqrt(4))

set.seed(1)

iris_cforest <- cforest(PetalLength~SepalLength+SepalWidth+PetalWidth+Species,controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000,mtry=mtry))

iristree <- get_cTree(iris_cforest)

iristree

plot(iristree)

set.seed(1)

iris_ctree <- ctree(PetalLength~SepalLength+SepalWidth+PetalWidth+Species)

iris_ctree

plot(iris_ctree)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please provide a _minimal_ and _reproducible_ example for your problem, then we can have a look. For some recommendations for this, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610

Comment: Thank you - I have added an example, hope this is okay.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually, I'm not sure where the different numbers of observations come from but I'll ask Torsten, as the main author and maintainer. (Comment: In `partykit` there is a more flexible tree/forest implementation but the `cforest` model implementation is not fully backward ompatible to `party`.)

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at using partykit::cforest followed by gettree, but in fact that gives me a sum of weights that is less than the total sample size (I assume because I have just extracted a single tree that is based on a subset of the data?).

Really what I'm trying to achieve is to extract a representation of the rules that the conditional forest would use to predict the response variable, if I gave it a new set of data. I don't know if I'm barking up the wrong tree (!) with what I'm doing here.